# detecting clicks not working

Tags: java, swing, label, mouselistener

So, I've been doing this code using JFrame where I have to change an label foreground color to one selected from a jcolorchooser, first thing i tried unsuccessfully to use the "Mouseclicked" event from the colorchooser element and it just doesn't work, I think I know why but Im not sure so lets just leave it in "it doesn't work properly", I´ve been trying other options and i endup with the one i think could be the most effective, implementing mouselistener but I think Im not using it as i should becouse it is not working and right now Im just really tired, so can you guy give me a hand? here is the code:

```
public class dieztres extends javax.swing.JFrame implements MouseListener{

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    mylabel.setForeground(mycolorchooser.getSelectionModel().getSelectedColor());
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
```

}

getting everything useless out of the way(like auto generated code) thats the important parts and I want to apologize if this is basic stuff, Im new in this area.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `MouseListener` is not enough. You must also register your class with a `Component`. A `JFrame` is a `Component` and your class is a `JFrame`, so just put `this.addMouseListener(this)` somewhere convenient such as the constructor method.

Comment: What Albert wrote is correct. First make sure that mouse listener works (by making it print a message for example). After you make sure it works, you need it to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Color Choosers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html) which demonstrates how you might solve your problem...

Directly from the tutorial...

```
tcc.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(this);
. . .
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    Color newColor = tcc.getColor();
    banner.setForeground(newColor);
}
```

Make sure make use of the available tutorials and consult the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html) when you have issues, they often have solutions for the more common issues